# PHPCrawler library can't get content

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, curl, web-crawler

I'm using PHPCrawler class to get product titles from different stores such as eBay, the library does well with all stores I'm supporting in my application except [Blink store website](http://blink.com.kw) the website's search page is not normally initiated like other store websites, when I have followed the website's requests through Chrome Debugger I found that it is initiated by script, though the request url is identical to the original url I enter to the address bar on Chrome and the url I set in the class to crawl.

So is there any way for the crawler class to fetch the page that I'm redirected to? I've used the setFollowRedirects methods but with no luck, because the redirect is done on client side through javascript not in the headers. Besides I've found an extra post request made after the normal get request, I've tried to add post data too but I get the same result an empty result set, and when I output the fetched page I get it without the products listed.

Side Note: Blink store website is an ASP.net site, is this the cause that I can't crawl its pages?

**UPDATE**

I've tried to fetch the page using the standard php cURL function and echoed the response, the page is echoed incomplete and keeps refreshing.

Comment: Have you tried any developer tool, e.g. Fiddler, Chrome Developer Tools, to inspect the requests? HTTP method, request headers, etc. might matter. Alternatively you can use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) along with some crawler API, e.g. [unicrawler](http://bestmike007.com/unicrawler), to get what you want.

Comment: @bestmike007 Yes I have monitored the requests through developer tools, and found that the page initially shows up without product listing, at the beginning of the page there is a form tag with post method, that submits to the same link.

Then the page submits that form using javascript to refresh itself with the list of products, at the moment I'm trying to mimic this behavior by making another curl call using that form data as a new POST request. I'll let you know what happens. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally worked around the problem using cURL twice on the same remote page, the search results don't appear unless you have the valid cookies required by the website, so the first cURL request is for getting the cookies in a file first, then the other cURL request is used to fetch the content.

Just add the following lines before calling `curl_exec()`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
```